# Не срабатывает условие. Классы

Tags: c++

```
void task3() {
char faccheck[256];
class Student {
private:
    char name[256], secname[256], address[256], tel[256], fac[256], bd[256];
    int course;
public:
    void Fill() {
        cout << "Введите имя студента: "; cin >> name;
        cout << "Введите фамилию студента: "; cin >> secname;
        cout << "Введите адрес студента: "; cin >> address;
        cout << "Введите телефон студента: "; cin >> tel;
        cout << "Введите факультет студента: "; cin >> fac;
        cout << "Введите дату рождения студента: "; cin >> bd;
        cout << "Введите курс студента: "; cin >> course;
    }
    void Show() {
        cout << "Имя и фамилия студента: " << name << " " << secname << endl << "Адрес студента: " << address << endl << "Телефон студента: " << tel << endl << "Факультет студента: " << fac << endl << "Дата рождения студента: " << bd << endl << "Курс студента: " << course << endl;
    }
    char* FacCheck() {
        return fac;
    }
};
Student S;
S.Fill();
cout << "Введите название факультета: "; cin >> faccheck;
if (faccheck == S.FacCheck())
    S.Show();
```

Проблема с последними тремя строчками, не понимаю почему условие не срабатывает, при вводе одинаковых значений.

UPD: Немного изменил код.

Comment: Ну нельзя выполнять присваивание массиву... Это в любом учебнике написано! Да и, кстати, в последнем стандарте уже и читать в массив типа `cin >> name;` запрещено...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, тупая ошибка, однако даже при изменения последнего условия на `if (faccheck == S.FacCheck())` оно не выполняется, при вводе одинаковых значений.

Comment: Опять же, сравнивается **адрес** массива `faccheck` с **адресом** же, возвращаемым `S.FacCheck()`. Они ожидаемо различны. Намек: почитайте о функции `strcmp`...

Comment: Строки так сравнивать тоже нельзя. Вы так сравниваете указатели. Используйте для этого `strcmp`. А лучше вообще используйте `string` вместо массивов `char`.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо.

Comment: @EOF Спасибо, учту про string.